# using fsolve to find the solution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

musun = 132712000000
T = 365.25 * 86400 * 2 / 3
e = 581.2392124070273


def f(x):
    return ((T * musun ** 2 / (2 * np.pi)) ** (1 / 3) * np.sqrt(1 - x ** 2)
        - np.sqrt(.5 * musun ** 2 / e * (1 - x ** 2)))


x = fsolve(f, 0.01)
f(x)

print x
```

What is wrong with this code?  It seems to not work.

Comment: It looks like there might be an error in specifying the denominator of your second `sqrt` parameter. Perhaps `np.sqrt(.5 * musun ** 2 / (e * (1 - x ** 2))))`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because `sqrt` returns `NaN` for negative argument, your function f(x) is not calculable for all real x. I changed your function to use `numpy.emath.sqrt()` which can output complex values when the argument < 0, and returns the absolute value of the expression.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
sqrt = np.emath.sqrt

musun = 132712000000
T = 365.25 * 86400 * 2 / 3
e = 581.2392124070273


def f(x):
    return np.abs((T * musun ** 2 / (2 * np.pi)) ** (1 / 3) * sqrt(1 - x ** 2)
        - sqrt(.5 * musun ** 2 / e * (1 - x ** 2)))

x = fsolve(f, 0.01)
x, f(x)
```

Then you can get the right result:

```
(array([ 1.]), array([ 121341.22302275]))
```

the solution is very close to the true root, but f(x) is still very large because f(x) has a very large factor: musun.

Answer (score 8):

`fsolve()` returns the roots of `f(x) = 0` (see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html)).

When I plotted the values of `f(x)` for `x` in the range -1 to 1, I found that there are roots at `x = -1` and `x = 1`. However, if `x > 1` or `x < -1`, both of the `sqrt()` functions will be passed a negative argument, which causes the error `invalid value encountered in sqrt`.

It doesn't surprise me that `fsolve()` fails to find roots that are at the very ends of the valid range for the function.

I find that it is always a good idea to plot the graph of a function before trying to find its roots, as that can indicate how likely (or in this case, unlikely) it is that the roots will be found by any root-finding algorithm.